# Dynamic SQL: String truncation in EXECUTE-Statment

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to monitor sizes of any databases in an SQL Server instance so I came up with this query that builds a temporary table which delivers what I want

```
/*DROP TEMP TABLE IF STILL EXISTENT*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sizes') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #sizes;
/*DECLARE CURSOR curs1 to query the names of all relevant databases*/
DECLARE curs1 INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR
select CAST(name AS varchar(MAX)) from sys.databases WHERE state_desc ='ONLINE' AND name NOT IN ('tempdb', 'master', 'model', 'msdb', 'sysdb', 'tempdb2')
/*Open Cursor*/
OPEN curs1
/*Declare Variable to hold the value of current db*/
declare @dbname varchar(MAX) = 'dummy'
/*Create the temporary table for results*/
CREATE TABLE #sizes (DBname varchar(MAX), physicalname varchar(MAX), TotalSizeMB INT, AvailableSpaceMB INT)
/*Query the datafile statistics for every database dynamically*/
WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN
FETCH NEXT FROM curs1 INTO @dbname
IF @@FETCH_STATUS != 0
BREAK;
EXECUTE('USE ' + @dbname + ';INSERT INTO #sizes
SELECT DB_NAME(), f.physical_name,
CAST((f.size/128.0) AS DECIMAL(15,2)), 
CAST(f.size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(f.name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS int)/128.0 AS DECIMAL(15,2))
FROM sys.database_files f;')
END
Select * from #sizes
/*Cleanup*/
DROP TABLE #sizes

CLOSE curs1
DEALLOCATE curs1
```

When the cursor fetches a string containing a "-", it splits the string at that point, leaving an incomplete database name, which can not be found. I isolated the `EXECUTE` function to be the problem. I assume this has to do with the change of of context when changing the database with the `use` command. But I also tried the datatypes `nvarchar`, `text` and `ntext` (which are not valid for local variables), `char` and `nchar` as well as `sysname`, which is the fieldtype of the sys.databases' "name"-column.
Any suggestions on how to stop this behaviour?

Comment: You don't need a cursor here. I really dislike cursors even for administrative tasks like this. I will post a simpler approach to this shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the database name:

```
'USE [' + @dbname + ']; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of how you can do this without using a cursor. It still requires dynamic sql but no cursor. :) I realize you are using FILEPROPERTY which will be NULL here but I tossed this example together quickly. And since I suspect you will probably continue to use the cursor version you already have I didn't refactor that piece.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 
'SELECT DatabaseName = ''' + name + ''', f.physical_name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
CAST((f.size/128.0) AS DECIMAL(15,2)), 
CAST(f.size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(f.name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS int)/128.0 AS DECIMAL(15,2))
FROM [' + name + '].sys.database_files f union all '
from sys.databases 
WHERE state_desc ='ONLINE' 
    AND name NOT IN ('tempdb', 'master', 'model', 'msdb', 'sysdb', 'tempdb2')

select @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)

select @SQL
--Uncomment the next line when you are comfortable the dynamic sql will work
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Thank you! That is very interesting. Especially since I am having trouble fetching the results of my solution in php5.

Comment: Much simpler than a cursor. :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the FILEPROPERTY-expression results in a NULL-value? The filename parameter expects nchar(128) data, but even when I use CAST, it does not work.

Comment: FILEPROPERTY is a function that is relative to the database it is currently executing on. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/fileproperty-transact-sql And in the code I put here the entire thing is run against one database. Thus FILEPROPERTY will return NULL because that file does not exist for the current database. Look closely and you will find that it returns values only for the database where you run this.